# Repairing or retrieving video off a cracked disk

Tags: data-recovery, dvd, repair, scratch

My disk has a thin crack right through the one side. Right around the crack it looks like it has water damage but I'm pretty sure it was caused from the crack.

Will tape work for this?

If there is no way to repair it, is there somewhere that I can take it so they might be able to somehow get the video off of it and onto another disk?

Answer (score 3):

If it has a physical crack, I wouldn't recommend attempting to salvage data since the spinning inside your drive might cause it do damage even further. I think your best bet is to take it to a specialist data recovery company. I'm sure google will help you locate one somewhere near you.

Comment: Example....http://www.diskdoctors.com/cd-recovery.asp